# how to print the for loop index with the input statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to print the counter of the for loop together with the input statement(inside for loop):
eg.

```
for i in range(n):
    ac[i] = str(input("Air conditioning available in room? In room number:"))
```

Expected output is

```
Air Conditioning available in room? in room number 1
Air Conditioning available in room? in room number 2
```

Comment: You need to prepare the `ac` list to have enough elements so you can access them with `ac[i]`. Any reason not to use `ac.append(input("Air conditioning available in room? In room number:"))` ?  (no need to "str" the input() - it already IS a string.)

Comment: By the by ... what is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
for i in range(1,n+1):

        ac[1] = input(f"Air conditioning available in room? In room number {i}:")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just format the string along with `i`:

```
for i in range(n):
    ac[i] = input(f"Air conditioning available in room? In room number: {i + 1}")
```

Or for versions without f-strings:

```
for i in range(n):
    ac[i] = input("Air conditioning available in room? In room number: {0}".format(i + 1))
```

Comment: Note: This only works with python 3.6 and above.

Comment: @The why? string literal interpolation is in since 3.6 ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner My mistake. I tried it in 3.5, and it didn't work. Then I tried in 3.8, and it worked, so I automatically assumed it would only work for 3.8.